# Cordova Contact Plugin Help for Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a small app up and running using phonegap. I want to install the contact plugin, but am having trouble.

I have installed node, used npm to install cordova and phonegap, and then the contacts plugin. However, I am not able to use the contact plugin.

There is a very good chance that I installed things in the wrong directories. Is there a way to check? Or can anyone tell me exactly which directories I should be in when I install cordova/plugins?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you could tell us which error you get when you try to use the plugin. In google chrome you can go to **chrome://inspect** (make sure your device is plugged in).

Do you have the plugin configured in your config.xml?:

```xml
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" version="1.1.0" />
```

If you wonder how I got this configuration line. I got it from here:
https://build.phonegap.com/plugins